# Netbeans doesn't output application tests

Tags: netbeans, project, program-entry-point

Is it possible to output automaticaly the result of testing each application of a project in Netbeans? I mean output the result with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, so that I do not need to change everytime the main class of my project in the properties.

Explanation:
My project has many classes with main methods
so to see the output of one specific application I need to go to:

- Right click on the project and scroll down to the Properties
- Select run on the left
- And then change to the main class I want.

So my question is: is it possible to do it automatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> :)
Having one main methode in the package is recommended!
Thanks